# How to init a new object from an existent one of its superclass in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I know this kind of question has been asked many times, but looking around I just couldn't find a solution to fit my problem.
I have a class called, say, `Base` from a framework I'm using, and I need to expand its features while still being able to access its original methods and properties. Since both the framework and my code will be contemporaneously and asynchronously working with the same `Base` object, I need both to be able to do so. So I thought: subclassing.
But it's not just about subclassing: what I need is more similar to a downcasting. It's that I need to access my own defined properties from an object that should still be a `Base`object to the framework. So let's say I create a `Derived` subclass to do the job: how to init? I can't just use a copy constructor since I need to work with the same objects the framework is handling. And I can't use categories, I need to add ivars.
Do you know any way this can be done?

Comment: You can add fake ivars to a category: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Comment: I haven't tried, since I couldn't imagine a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have access to not only the `Base` methods and iVar's, but the actual values of the iVar's stored in a **specific instance** of the `Base` class.  This sounds like a perfect example of when you want to use composition.  A composite class is your own custom class with its custom methods and iVars, which also contains an instance of your `Base` class.

```
@class Base;

@interface Derived : NSObject {
    Base *baseObject;
    // Add your iVar's here.
}   
// Add your declared properties/methods here
@end
```

Now, when you create your `Derived` instance you need to assign the instance of `Base` that you want to have access to:

```
Derived *derivedInstance = [[Derived alloc] init];

// Now set the baseObject.  This could also be set by the Derived class itself if 
// you are creating a new instance or are accessing a "known" object 
// (ie Singleton or global object).
derivedInstance.baseObject = myBaseObjectThatIWantToAccess;

NSLog("Derived iVar: %@", derivedInstance.<ivar>);
NSLog("Base Object iVar: %@", derivedInstance.baseObject.<iVar>);
```

**Note 1** You could also add methods to `Derived` which would "hide" `baseObject` so that you don't have to expose it to the outside world.

**Note 2** I would also recommend using declared properties instead of iVars in most cases, but the example above shows iVars since that is what you asked about.

Comment: Isn't that simply *encapsulation*?

Comment: @trojanfoe - No.  If you want to see a good Cocoa explanation from Apple, take a look at:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW22  The last paragraph of the "When to Make a Subclass" section discusses using composition  instead of a subclass.  Encapsulation would be the last paragraph (hiding the internal implementation from the outside world.)